# How to get rid of the navigation pane?

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2010 application that has a default form.  I do not want users to see or to be able to unhide the navigation pane.  I tried unchecking the display navigation pane option in the current project options but its still there.  I don't want the pane to be minimized (that is, pushed off to the left).  I want it completely gone.  I know it's possible because I have seen an application where the navigation pane is not there at all but I don't know how the developer did it. I do not think it was done using VBA. Ideas?
Thanks,
Taffy

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=access%20hide%20navigation%20pane

Comment: No, the vertical bar is still there for the users to show / hide the nav pane.  I don't want that vertical bar there at all

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation pane using the current database options and unchecking the 'Display Navigation Pane'. You'll need to re-start the database for this to take effect.

If the bar is still displaying then there is something happening with your start up form.

Try creating a completely new database file with a single blank form and set this form to be the startup display form and uncheck the navigation pane to verify that this method works. Then check your main application to see what is different.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the database option should hide the navigation pane, but if it doesn't, you could try the following code:

```
Function HideNavigationPane()  
DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "TableName", True  
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide  
End Function
```

Replace "TableName" with the name of one of your tables, and that should hide the navigation pane.